# Save pillow objects to S3 with django_storages

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, python-imaging-library

I want to save in S3 from Amazon an image that I resize with Pillow. That image is uploaded by the user and I will upload it once resized. That is, it does not exist in S3.

Currently I'm doing it as follows:

Being a list of Pillow objects

```
def upload_s3(files):
    for f in files:
        print(f)
        path = default_storage.save('/test/cualquiersa/')
        f.save(path, "png")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `boto3` to upload files to s3.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')
# For more client configuration http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

def upload_s3(files):
for f in files:
    print(f)
    response = client.put_object(
        Body= f,
        Bucket=<bucket_name>,
        Key=<location/directory>
    )
# More code here
```